# Sorting a NumPy array and permuting another one along with it

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have two, numpy arrays, the first, `A`, being one-dimensional, the second, `B`, is two-dimensional in the application I have in mind, but really could have any dimension. Every single index of `B` covers the same range as the single index of `A`.

Now, I'd like to sort `A` (in descending order) but would like to permute every dimension of `B` along with it. Mathematically speaking, if `P` is the permutation matrix that sorts `A`, I would like to transform `B` according to `np.dot(P, np.dot(B, P.T))`. E.g. consider this example where sorting coincidentally corresponds to reversing the order:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([1,2,3])

In [3]: B = np.random.rand(3,3); B
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.67402953,  0.45017072,  0.24324747],
       [ 0.40559793,  0.79007712,  0.94247771],
       [ 0.47477422,  0.27599007,  0.13941255]])

In [4]: # desired output:

In [5]: A[::-1]
Out[5]: array([3, 2, 1])

In [6]: B[::-1,::-1]
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.13941255,  0.27599007,  0.47477422],
       [ 0.94247771,  0.79007712,  0.40559793],
       [ 0.24324747,  0.45017072,  0.67402953]])
```

The application I have in mind is to obtain eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a nonsymmetric matrix using `np.linalg.eig` (in contrast to `eigh`, `eig` does not guarantee any ordering of the eigenvalues), sort them by absolute value, and truncate the space. It would be beneficial to permute the components of the matrix holding the eigenvectors along with the eigenvalues and perform the truncation by slicing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get sorted indices of `A`. Then you can use these indices to rearrange `B`.

It is not entirely cear how you want to rearrange B...

```
p = np.argsort(A)

B[:, p][p, :]  # rearrange rows and column of B
B.transpose(p)  # rearrange dimensions of B
```

If you want to order eigenvectors according to eigenvalues, you should only rearrange the columns of the eigenvectors:
(Also, it may make sense to use the absolute value, in case you get complex eigenvalues)

```
e, v = eig(x)
p = np.argsort(np.abs(e))[::-1]  # descending order
v = v[:, p]
```

Comment: You are right of course that I only need to rearrange the columns of the eigenvector matrix. Thanks for pointing that out, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.argsort` to get the index mapping. For example:

```
test=np.array([2,1,3])
test_array=np.array([[2,3,4],[1,2,3]])
rearranged_array=test_array[:,test.argsort()]
```

Here, `test.argsort()` yields `[1,0,2]`.